# Xdebug (Vagrant) not working with SublimeText 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug on my Vagrant server and the XdebugClient plugin for Sublime Text 3. When I start debugging, my page loads in the browser but nothing shows up in the context, watch or stack tabs. The xdebug.log file is also empty. The following are my settings:

**php.ini**

```
[CUSTOM]

error_reporting=1
display_errors=true
track_errors=1

[xdebug ]

zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.idekey=sublime.xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.15
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/profiler"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

**xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.15
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

***.sublime_project***

```
"settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://mysite.dev/",
            "path_mapping": {"/vagrant/www/mysite/dist" : "/Users/iii/Documents/Dev/vagrant/www/mysite/dist"},
            "super_globals": true,
            "close_on_stop": true,
        }
    }
```

***Xdebug.sublime-settings***

```
{
    "close_on_stop": true,
    "pretty_output": true,
    "launch_browser": true,
    "debug": true,
    "ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",
    "port": 9001,
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Xdebug log should be created .. as long as xdebug sees the xdebug COOKIE/GET/POST parameter. So .. try with `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` -- it will tell xdebug to attempt to debug every single request. If still nothing (not even xdebug log) -- what security software/packages do you have on your virtual machine (e.g. SELinux and alike).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem with Vagrant/Sublime/Xdebug. I found that the latest version of Xdebug (2.6.0) doesn't work well with Sublime. Evidently, there's an XML formatting issue.

I found two things that both solved the problem:

- Revert to Xdebug 2.5.5, or
- set `"super_globals": false,` in your config.

(https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/issues/172)

---

ETA 24 Oct 2018:

In my case, the solutions above were not necessarily a fix, but just helped to avoid the real issue in some cases. The real fix appears to require a change to the Sublime Package: https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/issues/172#issuecomment-410478057

I ended up forking the SublimeTextXdebug (assuming this is the package you're using), patching it, and then replacing the package with the patched version. (There's a pull request in the main repository, but I don't think it's been pulled yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has the same problem.  I was using Sublime 2 with Xdebug without any issues.  I upgraded to Sublime 3 and was not able to get Xdebug to break.  I went through various posts and tried various recommendations without success, until, I added the setting xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log".  No idea why, but once this was added, it started to work.